# Getting an error while creating a restore point

Tags: windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I get this error when I try to create a restore point, what should I do to solve the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has [this suggestion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-system/system-restore-error-message-0x80042308/e00b5814-10d3-46cb-90c7-68115755185d) (which works for Vista and 7):

> Run [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) - a malware removal tool
>   Run the Vista System File Checker Tool (you'll use the command line here, details in the above link)
>   Try again

The page there is a bit more detailed, let us know how it goes.

Comment: I did those two steps. No malwares were found and no violation! And I still get that error when trying to create a restore point. But thank you for your answer and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do an `sfc /scannow` at the command prompt.  That will check your system files for corruption.

Also, antivirus software might be interfering.  You might try to TEMPORARILY disable any antivirus or similar software you have running.

If neither of those work, it could be related to the Volume Shadow Copy service.  Go into Services and see if it is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did not work.